# IIS anonymous authentication

Tags: iis-10

My IIS server is not accepting connections from any other machines. I have enabled anonymous authentication but when I access http://x.x.x.x:8080 from any other machine, its still asking for credentials. When I access http://x.x.x.x:8080 where IIS is installed, everything works perfect. Also I create a inbound rule for port 8080 in the IIS webserver machine.IIS version is 10.0.Please help

Comment: Is your x.x.x.x server in an AD domain?

Comment: No. Its in workgroup

Comment: check that all other authentication methods disabled

Comment: Also check that anonymous user has read access to web app directory.

Comment: Every authentications methods are disabled. When I apply anonymous user "brad" read access to the web app directory which contains dll files as well as asp.net files,its not accepting my read permission and showing some errors

Comment: Just to make clear. when you say "Every authentications methods are disabled" I assume you still have anonymous authentications enabled?

Comment: Yeah, anonymous authentication is enabled and Its working now. Thanks for your support skalinkin. Cheers